# Why isn't this type guard for string working?

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

I have a TypeScript method which accepts a parameter. The parameter can be either of type `string` or type `Object`. When I use a `typeof` check for type `string` in the method body, I still get error stating that `indexOf` and `substr` are not found on type `string | Object`.

As far as I understand the `if` block body should be type-guarded by the condition. What am I doing wrong?

```
function mergeUrlParameters(sourceParameters: string | Object, targetUrl: string, overwrite: boolean = false): string {

  var sourceParamObject: Object;
  if (typeof sourceParameters === "string") {
    if (sourceParameters.indexOf("?") >= 0)
      sourceParameters = sourceParameters.substr(sourceParameters.indexOf("?") + 1);
    sourceParamObject = $.deparam(sourceParameters, true);
  } else {
    sourceParamObject = sourceParameters;
  }

  ...
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with latest TypeScript installed (1.8.x).

**UPDATE**

It turned out that the reassignment of the `sourceParameters` variable causes the type-guard to fail. I've posted a related potential bug report about this behavior [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8022). In the meantime, several easy workarounds are available, I chose to inline the check and substring call with a `?` conditional expression.

Comment: I found this question because I am looking for a way to have an inline conditional (the ?) to be type guarded. Are you saying that when you used the inline conditional, it was type guarded automatically? I couldn't get it to do this for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast it to the appropriate type:

```
function mergeUrlParameters(sourceParameters: string | Object, targetUrl: string, overwrite: boolean = false): string {
    var sourceParamObject: Object;

    if (typeof sourceParameters === "string") {
        if ((<string> sourceParameters).indexOf("?") >= 0) {
            sourceParameters = (<string> sourceParameters).substr((<string> sourceParameters).indexOf("?") + 1);
        }
        sourceParamObject = $.deparam((<string> sourceParameters), true);
    } else {
        sourceParamObject = sourceParameters;
    }

    ...
}
```

---

#### Edit

If you want to avoid that casting, you can create your own type guard (which you haven't in your code):

```
function isString(x: any): x is string {
    return typeof x === "string";
}
```

and then:

```
function mergeUrlParameters(sourceParameters: string | Object, targetUrl: string, overwrite: boolean = false): string {
    var sourceParamObject: Object;

    if (isString(sourceParameters)) {
        if (sourceParameters.indexOf("?") >= 0) {
            sourceParameters = sourceParameters.substr(sourceParameters.indexOf("?") + 1);
        }
        sourceParamObject = $.deparam(sourceParameters, true);
    } else {
        sourceParamObject = sourceParameters;
    }

    ...
}
```

more info in [TypeScript Handbook | typeof type guards](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Advanced%20Types.md#user-content-typeof-type-guards)

---

#### 2nd edit

Ok, after playing around with it for a while I understand what is the compiler problem with your code.
This variation of your code compiles with no errors:

```
function mergeUrlParameters(sourceParameters: string | Object, targetUrl: string, overwrite: boolean = false): string {
    var sourceParamObject: Object;

    if (typeof sourceParameters === "string") {
        sourceParamObject = $.deparam(sourceParameters.indexOf("?") >= 0 ? 
                sourceParameters.substr(sourceParameters.indexOf("?") + 1)
                : sourceParameters
            , true);
    } else {
        sourceParamObject = sourceParameters;
    }
}
```

The main difference being that in your code you reassign a value to `sourceParameters` and that probably confuses the compiler.

To illustrate the issue, consider this simple example:

```
function x(param: number | string): number {
    var num: number;

    if (typeof param === "string") {
        num = parseInt(param);
    } else {
        num = param;
    }

    return num;
}

function y(param: number | string): number {
    if (typeof param === "string") {
        param = parseInt(param);
    } 

    return param;
}
```

function `x` compiles without errors, but `y` has the following error:

```
Argument of type 'number | string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

(check it out in [the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20x(param%3A%20number%20%7C%20string)%3A%20number%20%7B%0D%0A%09var%20num%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09if%20(typeof%20param%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22string%22)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09num%20%3D%20parseInt(param)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09num%20%3D%20param%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09return%20num%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20y(param%3A%20number%20%7C%20string)%3A%20number%20%7B%0D%0A%09if%20(typeof%20param%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22string%22)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09param%20%3D%20parseInt(param)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%20%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09return%20param%3B%0D%0A%7D))

Comment: The whole sense of type guards is to not need casts inside a guarded block of code, so while your answer is working, I actually can't accept it.

Comment: In my case the user-defined version is not working either. In the linked docs it's written that simple `typeof` guards can be inlined. It seems like I have some special circumstances around. It's a small piece in quite a big project.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási finally understood what you want and what the problem is, check my revised answer.

Comment: oh, I see you find out about it yourself

Comment: @ZoltánTamási thanks, next time you can also answer your own question and mark it as accepted instead of adding it to your question